# cfdocument how can I resize the footer height?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdocument

How can I resize the footer in a cfdocument creating a PDF?

```
<cfdocument format="pdf">
    <cfdocumentitem type="header">
      My Header
    </cfdocumentitem>
    <cfdocumentitem type="footer">
      This text I want to be my footer but I want it to be much bigger. I have a lot of legalize and I need more room so it will be readable.
    </cfdocumentitem>
</cfdocument>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `cfdocument` tag, try using the `marginbottom` attribute to bring up the lower margin of the content area.